# RewriteRule/RewriteCond String Matching

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using a RewriteRule to redirect a subfolder called /shop/ to root of new site which works perfectly.

```
RewriteRule ^shop/?(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

I now want to include a condition above that can match a path like below

old site - www.domain.com/shop/**brand-name**

and rewrite it to:

new site - www.domain.com/brands/**brand-name**

where it matches on the **brand-name** part and performs a 301 redirect. Can mod_rewrite do this? It's important it matches on the brand-name effectively swapping /shop/ for /brands/ but not effecting the RewriteRule I have above because that works perfectly for everything else. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got you wrong but this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/brand-name$ /brands/brand-name [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^shop/?(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The trick is that you add the new rule before your existing rule. Together with the L option you avoid that your other rules are executed.

If you have multiple bands (what I expect) than you can list them this way:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/(brand-name|other-brand|third-brand)$ /brands/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Ah maybe I didn't explain this well. Basically I have nearly 200 brands so I need a more robust solution otherwise I might as well list them manually on each line. I'm wondering if RewriteCond or RedirectMatch would help. I'm basically looking for it to match the old brand-name with the new brand-name so then and only then it swaps /shop/ with /brands/ whilst the rest of the time it just removes /shop/ entirely as with the 2nd RewriteRule which works perfectly for me!

Comment: How should mod rewrite guess that something behind /shop/ is a brand and nothing else?